# importing third party json feed as custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, json

I have a third party json feed http://feeds.artlogic.net/artworks/artlogiconline/json/ that i need to use to import data in wordpress as a custom post type called "artwork".

Are there are handy plugins that could map this data. Or are there any handy api that would make this easier to code. I'm newest to wordpress development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the D.I.Y. route...

The post type in this example is set to 'post' but you can see where to change it. Here is a working example to pull the data ( first page in this example ), parse the response, create a class for the clean(er) data, generate posts from that data then update the post meta for specific attributes.

You'll want to adjust what triggers the call but this will create 5 posts when you hit the front-end. They will check and make sure the title doesn't already exist as well as the slug before they are generated.

The content is just set from the artwork_html + I added the img url in there. You'll probably want to fetch that image into your database using `media_sideload_image`.

```
<?php

if (!class_exists('RemoteArtwork')) :
    class RemoteArtwork
    {
        // original data
        public $raw;

        // public items
        public $title;
        public $artwork_html;
        public $id;

        public function __construct($dirty_data)
        {
            $this->parse_data($dirty_data);
        }

        /**
         * Clean the data, never expect good data
         */
        private function sanitize_remote_data($data_as_array)
        {
            foreach ($data_as_array as $inx => $data) {
                $data_as_array [$inx] = sanitize_text_field($data);
            }
            return $data_as_array;
        }

        /**
         *  Take the dirty data, clean it, then set our properties
         */
        private function parse_data($dirty_data_as_array)
        {
            $clean_data = $this->sanitize_remote_data($dirty_data_as_array);

            // save the raw data (cleaned)
            $this->raw = $clean_data;

            // grab the values we need
            $this->title = $this->raw ['_title'];
            $this->artwork_html = $this->raw ['artwork_html'];
            $this->id = $this->raw ['id'];
        }

        /**
         * Update a post with the latest meta data
         */
        public function update_artwork_post_meta($post_id)
        {
            $meta_values_to_set = array (
                '__artwork_dimensions' => $this->raw['dimensions'],
            );

            foreach($meta_values_to_set as $key => $meta_value){
                $success = $this->update_meta($post_id, $key, $meta_value );
            }
        }

        public function update_meta ( $post_id, $key, $meta_value ){
            if ( isset( $meta_value ) && 0 < strlen( trim( $meta_value ) ) ) {
                return update_post_meta ( $post_id, $key, $meta_value );
            }
            return false;
        }

        public function get_meta ( $post_id, $key ){
            $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, true );
            return empty( $value ) ? null : $meta_value;
        }

    } // RemoteArtwork
endif; // RemoteArtwork


if (!class_exists('RemoteArtworks')) :
    class RemoteArtworks
    {
        /** data from url */
        public static $remote_data;

        /** parsed data -- use these instances for stuffs */
        public static $artworks;

        /**
         * Pull the main feed & extra pages
         */
        private static function GetRemoteArtworks($url)
        {
            // remote data
            $response = wp_remote_get($url);

            if (is_wp_error($response) || !isset($response['body'])) return; // bad response

            // the good stuff
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

            if (is_wp_error($body)) return; // bad body

            // decode the data
            $data = json_decode($body, true);

            if (!$data || empty($data)) return; // bad data

            // make sure there isn't anymore
            if (isset($data['page']) && isset($data['no_of_pages'])) {
                $page = $data['page'];
                $pages = $data['no_of_pages'];
                $next_page_link = $data['next_page_link'];
                if ($page !== $pages) {
                    // keep loading data from $next_page_link.....
                }
            }

            // final remote data
            return $data;
        }

        /**
         * Load the remote feed and parse the data
         */
        public static function LoadRemoteArtworks($to_create_posts)
        {
            self::$remote_data = self::GetRemoteArtworks('http://feeds.artlogic.net/artworks/artlogiconline/json/');

            if (!isset(self::$remote_data ['rows'])) return; // no rows --- booo!

            $works = array();
            foreach (self::$remote_data ['rows'] as $inx => $remote_item_data) {
                // create artwork instance
                $artwork = new RemoteArtwork($remote_item_data);
                $works[] = $artwork;
            }

            // set our local data that has been cleaned and parsed
            self::$artworks = $works;

            // let's make new POSTS!!!
            if ($to_create_posts) {
                $count = 0;
                foreach (self::$artworks as $inx => $artwork) {
                    $count++; // for demo ---- let's not go overboard here

                    $post_id = self::CreateLocalArtworkPost($artwork);

                    if ($post_id == -1) {
                        // Nothing happened
                    } else if ($post_id == -2) {
                        // already exists
                        // ... I guess we could update a post's data here...
                    } else {
                        // new post was created, let's update it's meta
                        $success = $artwork->update_artwork_post_meta($post_id);
                    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
if ($count >= 5) return self::$remote_data; ///////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////// FOR DEMO... DON'T DO EVERY POST
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////// BUT YOU COULD...
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }
            }

            // return the remote data... for whatever reason outsite of this class
            return self::$remote_data;
        }

        public static function CreateLocalArtworkPost($artwork)
        {
            if (!$artwork) return -1;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DEBUG
// echo '<pre>';
// print_r( $artwork );
// echo '</pre>';
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // do post creation from $artwork data that has been sanitized

            $template = ''; // add a custom template if you want

            $post_type = 'post';

            $img_url = $artwork->raw['img_url'];
            $artwork_html = $artwork->artwork_html;

            $content = "<p>${artwork_html}</p>\n\r<br />\r\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"${img_url}\"><img width=\"100%\" height=\"auto\" src=\"${img_url}\"></a>";

            $new_post_id = self::CreateNewArtworkPost($post_type, $artwork->title, $content, $template, $artwork);

            return $new_post_id;
        }

        /**
         * orginal from - https://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-a-post-in-wordpress/
         */
        public static function CreateNewArtworkPost($post_type = 'post', $title, $content, $template_rel_path = '', $data)
        {
            // Initialize the page ID to -1. This indicates no action has been taken.
            $post_id = -1;

            if (!current_user_can('publish_posts')) {
                // sorry...
                return $post_id;
            }

            // Prep
            $author_id = get_current_user_id();
            if (!$author_id) {
                return $post_id;
            }

            $title = sanitize_text_field(wp_strip_all_tags($title)); // remove any junk
            $title = esc_html(wp_unslash($title));
            $slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($title); // converts to a usable post_name
            $post_type = post_type_exists($post_type) ? $post_type : 'post'; // make sure it exists

            // If the page doesn't already exist, then create it (by title & slug)
            if (null == get_page_by_title($title) && empty(get_posts(array('name' => $slug)))) {

                // Set the post ID so that we know the post was created successfully
                $post_id = wp_insert_post(
                    array(
                        'post_name' => $slug,
                        'post_title' => $title,
                        'post_content' => $content,
                        'post_type' => $post_type,
                        'post_author' => $author_id,
                        'comment_status' => 'closed',
                        'ping_status' => 'closed',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                    )
                );

                if ($post_id && $post_id > 0 && !empty($template_rel_path)) {

                    // make sure the template exists
                    $template_full_path = trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()) . $template_rel_path;
                    if (file_exists($template_full_path)) {

                        // set the post meta data -- use relative path
                        update_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', $template_rel_path);
                    }
                } // end template check

                // Otherwise, we'll stop
            } else {
                // Arbitrarily use -2 to indicate that the page with the title already exists
                $post_id = -2;

            } // end if

            return $post_id;

        } // end programmatically_create_post

    }// RemoteArtworks
endif; // RemoteArtworks
```

Then Kick off the remote fetch and creation

```
add_action ( 'init', function(){

  // break time in the demo... run on the front and watch the posts pile up
  if( is_admin() ) return;

  // Create posts from remote data?
  $to_create_posts = true;

  // Load the feed
  $data = RemoteArtworks::LoadRemoteArtworks( $to_create_posts );

});
```

**Reference**

- [Creating multiple page URL without creating the pages in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211338/creating-multiple-page-url-without-creating-the-pages-in-wordpress)
- https://tommcfarlin.com/saving-and-retrieving-post-meta-data/
- https://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-a-post-in-wordpress/

**Similar**

- [Import JSON feed to Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102277/import-json-feed-to-wordpress?rq=1)
- [Creating post content from external web scraper via JSON or RPC](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104922/creating-post-content-from-external-web-scraper-via-json-or-rpc?rq=1)

Comment: Really appreciate the response and your time. Going to step through this today. I'll feedback on the results. Thanks.

Comment: Update: Wow this worked first time.  Made my day :)